# How to add class to <ul> and childs <li> of sidebar widget - Wordpress

Tags: menus, widgets, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Note : Please note that I create this theme to re-sell, so I need little bit good way to add it.**

This is how I register the menus on my right sidebar:

```
if(function_exists('register_sidebar')){
  register_sidebar(array(
            'name'=>'sidebar_default',
            'before_widget' => '<div class="panel panel-info">',
            'after_widget' => '</div>',
            'before_title' => '<div class="panel-heading"><h4>',
            'after_title' => '</h4></div>'
        ));
 }
```

And this is the output:

```
<div class="panel panel-info">
   <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4>Title</h4>
   </div>
<div class="menu-openings-menu-container">
    <ul id="menu-openings-menu" class="menu">
       <li id="" class="menu-item-object-page menu-item-381"><a href="">Software</a></li>
       <li id="" class="menu-item-object-page menu-item-382"><a href="">Software</a></li>
       <li id="" class="menu-item-object-page menu-item-383"><a href="">Software</a></li>
       <li id="" class="menu-item-object-page menu-item-384"><a href="">Software</a></li>
       <li id="" class="menu-item-object-page menu-item-385"><a href="">Software</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

and this is how do it need the output to be able to use Twitter Bootstrap list-styles styles:

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
```

I appreciate all suggestions. Thanks.

[image: output]

[image: Source code]

Comment: which widget do you use to output that ?

Comment: @mmm I need to add `list-group` and `list-group-item` class to all default wordpress widject  like recent post widget, etc

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with just one site and not creating a theme maybe the easiest solution is to do it "manually". It is not the most "professional" way to do it, but it works.

Take a text widget or the new html widget, paste your code, for example:

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
```

and make the changes (to the links) manually.

Comment: It is not possible because I create this theme to re-sell.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to sell your theme as stated in your comments, and you want to make drastic changes to a nav menu to use in a widget, I'm not sure if even creating a walker could be the solution.

Instead, I suggest using a widget or shortcode for further usage. Here's a basic example, by using [`wp_get_nav_menu_items()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menu_items/):

```
add_shortcode('my-nav-menu','my_nav_menu_callback');
function my_nav_menu_callback($atts){
    $atts = shortcode_atts( 
        array(
            'location' => '',
        ), 
        $atts, 
        '' 
    ); 

    // Get the menu by its theme location
    $menu = get_term( $locations[$atts['location']], 'nav_menu' );
    $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);

    // Run a loop and output the menu
    $menu_list = '<ul class="list-group">';

    foreach( $menu_items as $menu_item ) {

        if( $menu_item->menu_item_parent == 0 ) {

            $parent = $menu_item->ID;

            $menu_array = array();
            foreach( $menu_items as $submenu ) {
                if( $submenu->menu_item_parent == $parent ) {
                    $bool = true;
                    $menu_array[] ='<li class="list-group-item">'.$submenu->title.'</li>';
                }
            }
            if( $bool == true && count( $menu_array ) > 0 ) {

                $menu_list .= '<li class="list-group-item">'.$menu_item->title.'</li>';

            } else {

                $menu_list .= '<li class="list-group-item">' . $menu_item->title . '</li>';
            }

        }

    }

    $menu_list .='</ul>';

    return $menu_list;
}
```

Now you can have access to your menu by using `[my-nav-menu location='menu-location]` in the content or any text widget.

Make sure you enable support for using shortcodes in text widgets first, by using:

```
add_filter('widget_text','do_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dynamic_sidebar_params` filter:

```
function dynamic_sidebar_before_filter ($params) {
    $params[0]['before_widget'] = str_replace('class="widget-container', 'class="widget-container w3-white w3-margin-bottom w3-card', $params[0]['before_widget']);
    $params[0]['before_title'] = str_replace('class="widget-title', 'class="widget-title', $params[0]['before_title']);
    return $params;
}
add_action('dynamic_sidebar_params', 'dynamic_sidebar_before_filter');
```